# How to force default test runner in WebStorm to be an npm configuration instead of mocha?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using WebStorm 2023.2.1. My org uses a tool called [chamber](https://github.com/segmentio/chamber) to access secrets when running tests locally. So when we run tests, we actually run `chamber`, and `mocha` (plus all of `mocha`'s arguments) are actually arguments to `chamber`.

Fortunately, we wrap this in an `npm run` command, and WebStorm is good enough to recognize from the integrated terminal that it can debug it. So from the terminal, I see the green highlight like so: [image] and I can do <kbd>Shift+Cmd+Enter</kbd> to run and debug the test. Great!

The problem I'm having is when I am working on test code and I see the little green run arrows next to functions and suites. For example:

[image].

This is useless to me because WebStorm wants to run it as a mocha test, and no matter how I mess with the default mocha configuration, it won't work. I need it to run as an `npm` run configuration, same as when I do <kbd>Shift+Cmd+Enter</kbd> from the terminal.

I've gotten close by hacking up the default mocha template to actually use npm as the "node interpreter" and passing my arguments to it in a way that works for running tests, but debugging doesn't work. It dies with an error

> Attaching debugger skipped (unhandled exception) Error: Command failed: `/Users/.../npm /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/javascript-debugger/debugConnectorPortPublisher.js`

Basically it looks like it is trying to use the node interpreter I told it to use to attach the debugger as well, but obviously `npm` is NOT `node`.

How can I change it so that the little green arrow kicks off an npm run configuration instead of mocha?